# Screen capture app that captures a window even when minimized?

Tags: macos, mac, video, screen-capture

I'm looking for a mac app that captures the screen (video) on specific app window (for example, Safari), and keeps recording what that window sees even when minimized to the dock for example.
Or even if a finder window is over it (without recording that finder window).

Anyone knows an app that can achieve what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 3):

You are making the assumption that windows are always updated when minimized. This is not the case. This also applies to apps present on other spaces.

In other words, this is not possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "windows are always updated when minimized"? If I'm looking at a Youtube video and minimize the browser window, it continues playing...right? So why wouldn't it be possible to keep recording what is going on in that window? I saw "http://wmrecorder.com/products/wm-capture/" that seems to be able to do what I need, but it's only for windows. They say "WM Capture 7 is the only screen capture software that allows you to screen capture video from windows that are minimized or hidden". I'm sure there's a Mac alternative

Comment: You make the assumption every system works the same way. This is not the case. Also a playing a video and displaying it are 2 separate things.

Comment: I never said every system works the same away. I said there's a program on windows that does it...I make the assumption that there's probably a Mac alternative.

Answer (score -1):

use debut video capture software, works for mac, for the feature you want, not for windows though.